# Akka persistence- How do storage plugins work?

Tags: cassandra, akka, opendaylight, leveldb, akka-persistence

I have been going through the Akka persistence documentation. In the storage plug-ins i.e. Journal and Snapshot sections, I see that these plug-ins can be customized in the following way...

```
# Path to the journal plugin to be used
akka.persistence.journal.plugin = "my-journal"

# My custom journal plugin
    my-journal {
  # Class name of the plugin.
     class = "docs.persistence.MyJournal"
# Dispatcher for the plugin actor.
  plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"
}
```

How does the plug-in class work?? I tried to put some print statements in my custom journal plug-in class(in all the methods and in some static blocks) but none of them are executing. The same thing happened in the snapshot plug-in class.
Even if some superclass is using the overridden methods in this class, at least the print statements should be executed. Does this mean this class is never accessed? How do I know these classes are working??

Comment: Please go-through the below link which explains the process for creating custom journal and snapshot plugins. http://bartoszsypytkowski.com/create-your-own-akka-net-persistence-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for this source. It explains the methods in Journal and snapshot store. I am concerned with how these methods are being called. I noticed plugin-dispatcher and tried to work with it and tried customizing also, but still these methods are not being called.